# Removing an Item in a list

Tags: c#, list, invalidoperationexception

I'm programming in c#. I'm trying to remove an item from a `List<>` but when I remove the item I get this exception error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Here is my code:

```
foreach (Target t in targetList)
{
    if (t.CalculateDistance(t.EndX, t.EndY) <= 5)
    {
        targetList.Remove(t);
    }
}
```

I get exception on first line. Why do I see this error? or How can I fix it?

Comment: you can't modify while enumerating.  do a for loop instead.

Comment: You can either: use a `for` loop, which I don't recommend, your `iterator` will likely end up out-of-range at some point; create a second `List` or `Array` to hold values you wish to remove, then add each value you wish to remove to the `List` or `Array` and after complete, iterate through that `List` or `Array` and remove those from the original `List` or `Array`.

Comment: `Your iterator will likely end up out-of-range at some point` not if you go backwards

Comment: @Plutonix That is true, though not recommended. As I said, *likely*. OP should refer to the LINQ query in the first answer here.

Comment: this is one reason why I hardly ever use foreach .  LOL

Answer (score 12):

The problem you face is that you can't modify the collection you itterate thru.
You could solve this by using linq:

```
targetList.RemoveAll(t => t.CalculateDistance(t.EndX, t.EndY) <= 5);
```

Comment: Valid answer, but it would be helpful if you described WHY the OP's solution wasn't working. That was the first part to his question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var needdelete = new List<Target>();

foreach (Target t in targetList)
{
    if (t.CalculateDistance(t.EndX, t.EndY) <= 5)
    {
        needdelete.Add(t);           
    }
}

targetlist.RemoveRange(needdelete);
```

Comment: This answer is ugly compared to the other, but does have the desired effect.

Comment: Valid answer, but it would be helpful if you described WHY the OP's solution wasn't working. That was the first part to his question.